# Customizing Zend Framework 2 Email Field Validator Error Messages

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I've got an Input Filter whose validator config for an email field looks like;

```
'validators' => array(
    array (
        'name' => 'EmailAddress',
        'options' => array(
            'messages' => array(
                'emailAddressInvalidFormat' => "Email address doesn't appear to be valid.",
            )
        ),
    ),
    array (
        'name' => 'NotEmpty',
            'options' => array(
                'messages' => array(
                    'isEmpty' => 'Email address is required',
                )
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

It works, that part is fine, but what I will get forever laughed at by the business units here, is if I put out an app that spits this error message to users:

The input does not match against pattern

> '/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/'

There's a strange nerd comedy buried in there (yes I realize it's accurate, but, rofl).

I have two questions for the kind souls here:

**How can I customize that error message?**  I can't seem to find the right key as I easily had for `'emailAddressInvalidFormat'`.

Also, **Is it possible to roll all the errors up into one?**  What I mean by that is.  Rather than posting:

> "Your email pattern just left the building & Your email cannot be
>   blank & Your email doesn't appear to be valid"

Can I put a "single failure" message for email?

> "Hey bud, check your email, something ain't right!"

Thanks for your help as always.

**UPDATE**

Vote for this bug here
https://github.com/zendframework/zend-validator/issues/41

Comment: To avoid multiple messages when there's an error, add in the validator `'break_chain_on_failure' => true,`.

Comment: I can use this in tandem with a single error message?  How to specify?

Comment: It seems like a bug in the EmailAddress validator to me. I usually just set one message to be used when the validator returns false: 'validators' => array(
      array(
       'name' => 'EmailAddress',
       'options' => array(
        'message' => 'Invalid e-mail address',
       )
      )
     ), (note the singular form of 'message'. This works except with the EmailAddress validator which still spits out the pattern match message which in fact comes from the Regex validator (NOT_MATCH).

Comment: Part 2: I walked through the code and it seems to happen when splitEmailParts returns false. It does look like it sets the correct error at that point though and then it just returns. Not sure where the Regex message comes from.

Comment: Re: customization of the error message; I created a issue report quite a while ago which appears to be fixed too. Please check the use case described in the message, does the fix work? https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/2538

Comment: @Jurian The custom message is being displayed, but still the Regex validator message shows up too. I just tried it in an empty test app with a form with only one field and then it works properly. The difference between the two test cases is that in the one where the (wrong) Regex message is being displayed the e-mail field is in a fieldset. Not sure if that has anything to do with it. I don't want to go off-topic too much so I will do some more research and if it really does turn out to be a ZF2 issue I will create a report.

Comment: Update: The difference is in the element type. If you use type Email it automatically attaches the RegexValidator and the free extra message in case it returns false. If you use a plain vanilla Text element you don't get this behavior.

Comment: So, the Email element registers an additional RegexValidator while if you use a text element with only the EmailAddress validator there is no regex validator attached? I'd say you set the `break_chain_on_failure` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677863/zf2-need-to-display-specific-error-message-on-specific-condition-failure) and set the error message inside the regex validator too.

Comment: @Jurian Yes, correct. The break_chain_on_failure will not prevent the Regex validation error from being shown. I'm also not sure if it's possible to set the message of the Regex validator either, because of the way it is implemented. The Email element implements the InputProviderInterface. In the getInputSpecification implementation is where this 'magic' happens. It calls getValidator(), which in case of no validators attaches the Regex validator. I would personally prefer to attach my own validators, which I actually want, instead of the element attaching its own validator.

Comment: @JurianSluiman, have tried what's in the test case and two error messages are shown nonetheless.  I have tried break_chain_on_failure as well, to no avail.  It's triggered by input that is not an email address.

Comment: I've found the issue, it's because Zend\Form\Element\Email adds its own default validator which is added atop whatever we configure as InputFilterSpecification.  It doesn't respect the `message` key, and poorly, even duplicates checks if we try to configure a custom EmailAddress validator in the InputFilterSpecification itself.  I'm under the gun on this one, so will switch to Text type with a customized EmailAddress validator instead.

Comment: Thanks for conversation here. It seems it is not fixed yet? Mine Zend version is 2.6 and this problem still exists.

Answer (score 4):

**Try this for custom message for email validation in ZF2:**

```
 'validators' => array(
                array( 
                    'name' => 'EmailAddress',
                    'options' => array( 
                        'messages' => array(
                        \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::INVALID_FORMAT => '"Hey bud, check your email, something ain\'t right!"' 
                        )             
                    )                   
                )             
            )
```

Answer (score 2):

According to ZF2, Email address validations are:

```
  $this->add(array(
        'name'       => 'email',
        'required'   => true,
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'EmailAddress',
                'options' => array(
                    'message' => array(
                        \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::INVALID =>   "Invalid type given. String expected",
                        \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::INVALID_FORMAT     =>"The input is not a valid email address. Use the basic format local-part@hostname",
                        \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::INVALID_HOSTNAME   =>"'%hostname%' is not a valid hostname for the email address",
                        \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::INVALID_MX_RECORD  =>"'%hostname%' does not appear to have any valid MX or A records for the email address" ,
                        \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::INVALID_SEGMENT    =>"'%hostname%' is not in a routable network segment. The email address should not be resolved from public network",
                        \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::DOT_ATOM           =>"'%localPart%' can not be matched against dot-atom format" ,
                        \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::QUOTED_STRING      =>"'%localPart%' can not be matched against quoted-string format",
                        \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::INVALID_LOCAL_PART =>"'%localPart%' is not a valid local part for the email address" ,
                        \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::LENGTH_EXCEEDED    =>"The input exceeds the allowed length",
                        ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

And additional validation could be <kbd>Regex</kbd> as stated above, and I also have <kbd>NoObjectExists</kbd> to make sure the email is not in my `db` ,if the email address is used to login:

```
array(
    'name'      => 'DoctrineModule\Validator\NoObjectExists',
    'options' => array(
        'object_repository' => $sm->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default')->getRepository('MyMudole\Entity\User'),
        'fields'            => 'email',
        'message'=>'This email is associated with another user! Please use another email',
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

“The input does not match against pattern” message seems to be `Zend\Validator\Regex::NOT_MATCH` actually, not of `Zend\Validator\EmailAddress` class.

From your code, it is not clear where and whether you make use of the `Regex` validator. I believe `EmailAddress` does not use `Regex` internally.

If you would like to customize the `Regex` message, it would probably look like this:

```
array (
    'name' => 'Regex',
    'options' => array(
        'messages' => array(
            'regexNotMatch' => "Not so nerdy message here.",
        )
    ),
),
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work, I receive 'No message template exists for 'regexNotMatch'.  ZF 2.2.6

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to especify just one message, but it should work as well:

```
    $message = sprintf(
        $this->getTranslate()->translate(
            '%s filled is not a valid e-mail address, please inform a valid in the field.'
        ),
        $entity
    );

    return array(
        'name' => 'EmailAddress',
        'options' => array(
            'messages' => array(
                \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::INVALID            => $message,
                \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::INVALID_FORMAT     => $message,
                \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::INVALID_HOSTNAME   => $message,
                \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::INVALID_MX_RECORD  => $message,
                \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::INVALID_SEGMENT    => $message,
                \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::DOT_ATOM           => $message,
                \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::QUOTED_STRING      => $message,
                \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::INVALID_LOCAL_PART => $message,
                \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::LENGTH_EXCEEDED    => $message,
            ),
        ),
        'break_chain_on_failure' => true
    );
```